# Text cut off when using When layout renderer combined with a colon

Tags: logging, nlog

In a File target, I'm using a **[When](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/When-Layout-Renderer)** layout renderer like this (simplified example):

```
layout="${when:when=1 == 1:inner=Test: Hello}"
```

I would expect the result to be **Test: Hello**. However, only **Hello** is logged, without **Test:**.

I've already figured out that it has something to do with the colon, and I've tried solving the issue using several methods:

- Escaping it with \
- Wrapping it in a [Literal](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Literal-Layout-Renderer) layout renderer
- Replacing it with its ASCII code &#58;
- Putting it in a separate variable

But none of them seem to work.

Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Apparently, this is a bug. I've [reported](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/444) this to NLog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/444) in the current version of NLog (3.1.0.0). A workaround is available:

```
layout="${when:when=1 == 1:inner=Test${literal:text=\:} Hello}"
```